# MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I set the `Install Packages on the Fly` setting to `Yes` and try to compile my document in Texmaker, but I still get the error `File [...] not found`, where `[...]` is the package I need. Basically, I need to manually install every package I use.

For example, I want to use the `footmisc` package. I put `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`, and I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'footmisc.sty' not found.`

Is this a known bug, or am I misunderstanding this feature?

Comment: You should keep the internet on and the repository address should be properly configured. Pl check them.

Comment: Yep, you're right @Harish, just had to configure my connection to the repository.

Comment: Just a note for the future, if you are using TexStudio or other IDEs on windows, open it with "run as an administrator" then packages will install "on the fly".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should first ensure that the internet is **ON**.
Then Go to

```
Start>all programs>MikTeX 2.9>Maintainance (Admin)>Package Manager (Admin).
```

This window will popup

[image]

Click Repository to get

[image]

Hope now the things will be clear.

Similarly the

```
 Start>all programs>MikTeX 2.9>Maintainance (Admin)>update (Admin).
```

should get you

[image]

Where you can select the source. Once it is done, the next time you can choose the second option i.e., `Last used package repository` if you have made the specific settings for a particular repository.

Comment: +1, but two remarks: 1) Afaik, MiKTeX is Windows-only, so your PS is redundant. 2) Why would it be preferable to select _Last used package repository_ the second time? What advantage do you get over keeping the option _Use the nearest package repository_?

Comment: @doncherry Thank you for noting. Yes PS is redundant. I removed it. Second option is only personal preference and nothing special about it.

Comment: I was having the same problem as OP, but specifying a repository did not help. I'm using TeXworks. 
! LaTeX Error: File `amssmyb.sty' not found.

Comment: I didn't find the package manager, yes  I do have miktex installed