# how to configure forward and inverse search with dviout and vim

Tags: texlive, vim

I installed TexLive, the entire 4GB+ and am using (learning vim as well going along) Latex-Suite with Vim for creating my tex files. The dvi viewer that came with TexLive is dviout.This is probably a very basic question but I cannot find the answer anywhere after banging my head for the whole evening on this..How do I set up the forward and inverse search with Latex-Suite/Vim and dviout. (I want to stick with dvi .. I know there will be suggestions for using pdf but its not a good feeling to give up on something without knowing the reason just because it does not solve the issue)

I did try adding the following lines to tex.vim

let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'

TCTarget dvi

as suggested on 
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart.html

when I do \ls after that, some command window like things pops up for a split second and goes away..

\lv works fine and I can see the dvi in dviout. but with \ls forward search it does not work.

For inverse search I could not find anywhere on the internet the whole evening how do I set it up..

I did not have this problem with forward/inverse search with Miktek and YAP with Latex-Suite for Vim. but I shifted to TekLive because I had problem similar to the following and his question seems to have been unsolved after 2 years so I assumed it is an unsolvable issue.
[Good at using TeX, bad at installing it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167112/good-at-using-tex-bad-at-installing-it)
So I prefer solution for TekLive.