# Miktex Package Installation

Tags: packages, miktex, subfloats, texmaker

I recently installed MiKTeX with the texmaker editor and cannot figure out how to update the packages. When I attempt to use the subfigure package with the following preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

I then get a prompt to install a new package, which I then set to the online directory at ctan. I then get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `subfig.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read >
```

How do I properly install packages to miktex? I'm absolutely confused. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at this [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)?

Answer (score 10):

Two ways:

1) Launch `MiKTeX Package Manager` from the `Start menu`, select the package you want to install and right-click on it to ask installation:

[image]

2) Launch `MiKTeX Options` and in the `General` tab, select `Ask me first` or  `Yes` for `Install packages on the fly`. Thus when a package is not installed, compilation will be interrupted to propose you to install the missing package, and will resume after installation:

[image]

Comment: How do I open the two windows you have there? I am using windows 8 and the only things that show up when i search for apps is the 'Miktex project page', 'texmaker', and 'texworks', none of which have options or a project manager for miktex.

Comment: Don't you have access to some `Start menu` in Windows 8? I'm sorry, I'm  under Windows 7, and don't know its interface. If you can use the `command shell` as administrator, launch it and type `mpm` for the first window, and `mo` for the other.

Comment: just realized i have the basic version of miktex... installing the full version, maybe that will make a difference. if not, I'll be back on with questions. and in windows 8, there is no start menu, but miktex would show up in the app search bar, which for me it does not.

Comment: Full version means > 2Gb… Do you want to type in hieroglyphic or classical Mongolian? In my opinion, you'd probably better install some software like `classic shell`, that give access to all applications the old way.

Comment: You do have an `All Programs` view in the `Windows 8` `Start Screen` it is accessed by clicking the arrow that is in bottom left corner of the `Home Screen`. Here you will find both the Admin and usual versions of `MiKTeX`'s package manager and settings, to get the admin versions to run in `Windows 8` you need to right click them and select `Run as administrator` else they will crash. With regards to downloading packages on the fly, this us by far the best option with `MiKTeX`, I have found some servers to drop occasionally. I've been using either Warwick's or Oxford's `FTP` servers lately.