# Mathtools.sty not found 'latex error'

Tags: packages, miktex, mathtools

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter to compose and execute my LaTeX file(s) on Windows 8.
When compiling, my code has this error:

```
Mathtools.sty not found
```

What should I do? How can I add this package?

Comment: Of course, I only now see that the accepted answer there notes that mathtools is unavailable in MikTeX since Oct. 1... nonetheless, it shows up on the website: http://miktex.org/packages/mathtools

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196555/32374

Answer (score 1):

Go to Miktex 2.9 settings and check if you allow "install package on the fly". If not, allow it.