# subplots 3X3 with one colorbar at the top

Tags: graphics, subfloats

[image]

I wanted to do 3x3 subplots with their colour bar shown north side, I want to write a code that puts them together as 3x3 subplots in Latex and then, I need to place thier colorbar at the north side. I posted a similar question before but the answer was for subplots that are all generated in matlab while what I need is to do 9 .eps files with one colorbar placed northside.

UPDATE: here I added an image of what I want, also I want to have the labels where the zero is and another 3 labels on top; one label for each ( directly below the colorbar).

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. A minimal example of what you have or what you have tried would be welcome. In case you don't have that… well, an image of what you want to achieve would also be welcome. In any case, more info and more effort on your side, would be appreciated.

Comment: I put the image, any help now?

Comment: More I read your question and more I think I didn't answer your real needs. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, if you want this result:

[image: tabular includegraphics figure rotating]

The code is the following, with the same recommandations of the previous one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\adjustimage{width=.94\textwidth}{}}\\
        &\begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            my caption 1 [NW]
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            my caption 2 [NN]
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            my caption 3 [NE]
        \end{adjustbox}\\
        \begin{sideways}my sideways 1\end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
        \begin{sideways}my sideways 2\end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
        \begin{sideways}my sideways 3\end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks RicoRally, this looks exactly what I want, many thanks!

Comment: RicoRally, I had to download a missing package from CTAN. The package "adjustbox" but then when I ran the adjustbox.tex file, I had an error about the first line in this file.The error was:! I can't find file `ydocstrip.tex. So, I still did not get your example to work with me because I am missing a package!

Comment: This happens when you fail the procedure to install the package. Package files' extension is `.sty`, not `.tex`. But don't worry, if you tell me the distribution you use, i'll be glad to help you. :) are you using `MikTeX 2.9`? Maybe you can ask a question on that and write here the link. Otherwise you can check this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196555/miktex-package-installation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but I think you are looking for something like this:

[image: image tabular includegraphics figure]

That can be achieved with a simple usage of the environment `tabular` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 1 [NW]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 2 [NN]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 3 [NE]
    \end{adjustbox}\\
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 4 [WW]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 5 [CC]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 6 [EE]
    \end{adjustbox}\\
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 7 [SW]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 8 [SS]
    \end{adjustbox}&
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.29\textwidth}
        my caption 9 [SE]
    \end{adjustbox}\\
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}&
    \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Be aware that this example won't work on his own**, the empty brackets `{}` (arguments of `\adjustimage`) need just to be filled with your image files.

I let the packages `adjustbox` and `booktabs` help me for a better graphical rendering. But that's not strictly necessary. For these cases, the concept is: "use just a well placed `tabular`!", and that will save you time. I prefer this approach rather than "bothering" myself with `floats` and automatic layout, because I want to be sure of the output in advance. Anyway nothing impedes you of putting your `tabular`s or `center` environments inside a `figure` environment, if that pleases you.

Comment: Doesn't any `\bigskip` risk to make the following tables properly skip to next page, if there's no vertical space enough? Or am I wrong since it's all inside `center`?

Comment: You're not wrong. To avoid that we could make use of a `figure` environment. I'm just editing because you never know...