# Question paper in LaTeX

Tags: exam, questionnaire

Is it possible to type a question paper using MiKTeX version 2.9?  How to install the `exam` package once I have already installed basic packages like `article`, `thesis`.

Comment: Hi and welcome, yes it is possible to typeset examsheets/questionaires. You can download packages like `exsheets`, `exam` or `tasks` using the MikTeX package manager.

Comment: A better duplicate might be [Miktex Package Installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196555).

Answer (score 2):

Open `MiKTeX Package Manager` (admin mode), select the `exam`  package in the list of packages, right-click on it and select `Install`.