# Question bank using latex

Tags: packages

Is there any packages that allow us to create a question paper from a bank of questions with different parts each with different weight and number of questions? Also we need to print the question number continuously.

Comment: Welcome, Found related question from the below links: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240999/question-paper-in-latex,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340727/constructing-question-bank

Comment: Have a look at the `exercisebank` package