# Where should I put the ( .sty) files to make packages work?

Tags: packages, miktex, cite-package

I'm using miktex and there are few packages that I don't have on my pc so I downloaded them , where should I put them to make them functional ( the folder name).

Comment: Just use the MiKTeX package manager to install missing packages.

Comment: I think http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196555/miktex-package-installation is a better choice for the duplicate. Packages should only be manually installed as a last resort. The TeX distribution's package manager should be used wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

If you only need the seperate downloaded packages for one project only, you can store them in the project folder.

---

The correct way to install packages using the MiKTeX Package Manager:

```
Start -> All Programs -> MiKTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance -> Package Manager
```

In the program choose either all needed packages by selecting them via

```
CTRL+click
```

and then start the download from

```
Task -> Install
```

Else you can download packages by

```
Edit -> Select All
```

or

```
Edit -> Select Installable Packages
```

The download is started as explained above. Uninstalling packages is analogue to the install procedure.

Comment: @mostafax80 marking answers as helpful is thanks enough ;)

Comment: new to the site, can't mark yet :D

Comment: @mostafax80 Yes, you can. You can *accept* answers even though you can't yet *vote* on them.