# Still not finding the .sty file even after package installation and refreshing file name database!

Tags: packages, miktex2.9, missing

[image]I am a beginner to LaTeX.

Problem started when I was typing some equation in TeXstudio and faced problem regarding missing packages, specifically the `.sty` file.

I looked upto some videos on the internet and followed the instruction as:

1. Downloaded `.zip` packages from ctan site
2. Extracted them in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`
3. Opened up the MikTeX Console, and ran the `Refresh file name database`

Still no luck with the missing packages.

However, I found that some of the packages didn't even contained the `.sty` file!

For Eg. I downloaded Stix package and extracted and all.
Just ran a curious search and it didn't have `.sty` file.
Similar with the rest 4 packages that I downloaded.

However, `txfonts` package had the necessary `.sty` file.
Still showing missing `txfonts.sty` however it's clearly there.
I've updated the name database twice-thrice after each step that I could take.
No use.

PS: The MiKteX console is showing the Stix and `txfonts` package listed, but the TeXstudio is reporting the error again and again.

Please Help.

Comment: You should (usually) not install packages directly from CTAN. Instead you should use the MikTeX package manager. Perhaps [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196555/miktex-package-installation) will help.

Comment: Don't install packages manually. Install the package with the MikTeX Console. Right click on the package in the screenshot you show and select install.

Comment: Some packages should go in tex\latex. But e.g. stix contains fonts and the files should go in various subfolders of the fonts folder. So unless you know exactly what you are doing don't install manually, and certainly not in the main miktex folder - you can create quite a chaos when doing it wrong. Use the miktex console to install packages.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you do not need to download `*.zip` files from CTAn manually.

As you can see in the MiKTeX console picture you added to your question the packages with name `*stix*` are **not** installed on your system, because you see no date in column `Installed on` ...

To get them installed click on the first listed package, hold shift and click on the last of the four listed packeges in your image. Then all 4  packages get blue, that means marked. Now you can click on the + sign to install them (see the red arrow in the following image showing the result on my system) ...

Please note that you can now see dates in the column `Installed on` ...

[image]

Comment: It may be worth adding that the user Should shut down any editor or pdf viewer and may need to add as admin and whilst the update system should automatically run the tasks for you , it is safest to run **Tasks**  **Refresh File Name DataBase** and **Refresh font map files** whilst your there and if running a dual admin/user system re-enter as user and run both tasks *to be sure* **to be sure**