# TeXstudio and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio

Can someone please run me through the steps to install the TikZ package on TeXstudio? I have been struggling for hours but just can’t seem to get it installed so that I can use it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: TeXstudio is just an editor for `tex` files. To compile the `tex` file you need TeXlive or MikTeX, for example. Did you install some?

Comment: Yes, I have MiKTeX installed.

Comment: @LuiP3rd Welcome to [tex.se]! I believe MiKTeX has a package manager for this.

Comment: I have installed the TikZ packages from MiKTeX's package manager, but still, TeXstudio won't allow me to compile TikZ commands.

Comment: Can you compile simple documents: `\documentclass{report}\begin{document}foo\end{document}`

Comment: I successfully compiled the code you just provided.

Comment: Type `kpsewhich tikz` in your command prompt (cmd) and hit enter to see if the package can be found.

Comment: I did as you asked and it's located under C:/Program Files/MiKTex/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex

Comment: What happens if you add `\usepackage{tikz} `to the preamble of the test Sigur provided? Does it compile?

Comment: Or try to add `\usepackage{tikz}` including a small example, e.g. `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\path (0,1) edge (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}`

Comment: Somehow I just got it to work! There was a package missing and after I installed it, it works perfectly! Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: You can set up MikTeX to install on the run the missing packages.

Comment: How do I do that Sigur?

Comment: LuiP3rd you should add a `@` in front of names otherwise people won't get notified (@Sigur)

Comment: @LuiP3rd, here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49343/14757

Comment: Sorry about that @Sigur and clemens (sorry, I can only notify one user). Thanks for all your time and effort to help me! This was driving me crazy, and I am very glad to have gotten it to work. Kind regards.