# What is wrong with my packages?

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker

I wanted to use these two packages:

- listings
- matlab-prettifier

to write code and highlight it like in Matlab and insert it in my pdf. 
I added the packages like this:

```
\usep­a­ck­age{list­ings}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
```

I am having trouble using them since when I try to compile I get this error:

`! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \usep
l.46 \usep
­a­ck­age{list­ings}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., \hobx), type I and the correct
spelling (e.g., I\hbox). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.46 \usep­
a­ck­age{list­ings}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.`

The document has a *begin{document}* line and it works fine until I try to add the new package.

I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly) to install packages on the fly for miktex  but it doesn't seem to help.

I don't undestand how to make it work, can someone please help me?

EDIT: The listings package seems to work in an example document such as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python}

 % Insert Pyhon examples here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeXmaker is an editor, you have to install packages through a LaTeX distribution. Have you installed mikTeX or TeXlive? (personally I would recommend TeXlive for new usersers)

Comment: I have mikTeX installed and it works perfectly with all other packages (babel, inputenc,fontenc...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Launch`MiKTeX Package  Manager (admin)` , right-click `listings` and `matlab-prettifier`and select `install`.

Comment: I think it's already installed, when I right-click the options are "uninstall" and "properties".

Comment: Please show the error message you got (all the lines in the log file from  `!` to `?` in a code section (`{}` button) so line endings are preserved) `\usepackage` is not undefined so you have presumably a wrong command somewhere that is not defined but you have not shown your input or the error message so it is hard to help

Comment: To anyone wondering how this simple typo question got 20.000 views - I have just noticed that this is one of the top Google results for "how to install latex packages on windows 10" - even though the answer had nothing to do with installation. I have already suggested a different (not very descriptive, admittedly) title - but in case it doesn't go through, I hope that some else can find a better one. At the moment it's very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something weird going on with the syntax higlighting of `\usep­a­ck­age{list­ings}` in your question. It almost looks like there are extra invisible characters in the command, between `\usep` and `ackage`. You might have accidentally copied them from somewhere.

The error message you posted in the comments also implies something of the sort.

As a posible solution, try deleting the line from your TeX file and retyping it by hand.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I probably copied the _usepackage_ from the library documentation. That's why I got the error.