# beamer.cls not found

Tags: beamer, miktex, installing, document-classes

I can't install beamer and have tried as many of the solutions in the other answers as I could understand (which was like, two of them).

Whenever I try to compile a beamer document, I get the classic "beamer.cls not found".

I have MikTex 2.9 on Windows 8.  I try to go into the settings for MikTex but I can't find it.  I search the whole MikTex 2.9 folder for "settings" and there are no results.  There is no folder called "maintenance" and literally all solutions I found involved going into such a file or folder.  I have the "latex-beamer-3.07" folder sitting on my desktop, and that's all I know about how tex works.  I have one folder, and I want to put it somewhere else so that I can use beamer.

Like, this is ***completely*** unintelligible to me:
[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

This is the 'solution' that all the other ones link to, which as I said I can't perform: [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)

Same here, I don't know where to get to the "options dialogue": [LaTeX packages: automatic versus manual installation, and related issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111125/latex-packages-automatic-versus-manual-installation-and-related-issues)

I don't know what "binary" means, I don't know what anything means haha  I just need to make this beamer for my thesis defense, which is tomorrow.  I have used beamer before so I don't understand why this is happening, but such is my life.  I just need to know where to plunk this beamer folder.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: As far as I remember, you should search the MikTeX folder in Windows Application menu. There is a link to MikTeX manager. If this doesn’t help, I would suggest you to reinstall MikTeX with the install package on the fly option activated by default. Binary means that the file is a program you can run.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaRYm3BZ1wU at about 1:45 for how to open the miktex update manager.

Comment: @sztruks would you like to convert your comment into a short answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you should search the MikTeX folder in Windows Application menu. There is a link to MikTeX manager. If this doesn’t help, I would suggest you to reinstall MikTeX with the install package on the fly option activated by default.

Binary means that the file is a program you can run.