# sty file not found

Tags: packages

I am trying to compile a template I have just downloaded but installation on the fly does not work, so I have tried to follow as explained here: [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)

but then I get the following problem:[image]

of course I have checked to have internet connection.
How can I fix this?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems you have an old version of MiKTeX Package Manager. You now have a `MiKTeX Console`, with a `Packages`, `Settings`, `Update` button. Perhaps you should update your MiKTeX installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve your problem, eihter install the newest version of MikTex along with installing all the packages your tex file requires or try using Overleaf, which will always be updated and doesn't require packages installation with the addition feature of allowing to work wherever you are.

Comment: Sorry, but overleaf used a fixed version of texlive. It is **not always updated** as you mentioned ...